# Remove Style from table in Code Behind

Tags: css, hide

This should be a lot easier than it appears to be, but I'm having an issue with it.

**Conditions**

1. If upon entering this specific page, if there is only one record in the grid (based on a status value in a dropdown), hide the grid and show a table with the details of that record.
2. If there is more than one record, display the grid with the records.
3. When a record is selected, display the table with the details of that record.

When I go into the page currently, there is only one record, so it is displaying the table. If I change the value of the dropdown to another status, more than one record is in the grid and the table is hidden. Previously (by another programmer) it was being set to Visible = false. Obviously, this is not a property of the table. However, it previously worked as when someone would select a row, they would set the Visible = true and the table would show.

I've now changed it to hide  by using:

```
tblDetails.Attributes("style") = "display:none"
```

However, trying to replace the Visible = true is not working:

```
tblDetails.Attributes.Remove("style")
```

I have also tried:

```
tblDetails.Attributes("style") = ""
```

Someone please point out to me the solution that is going to make me slap my forehead. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the answers given int this question could help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741612/show-hide-div-using-codebehind

Answer (score 1):

use `setAttribute(attr,value)` to change the value of each Element You want
like below example

```
yourelement.setAttribute("style","");//it is to change value 
yourelement.removeAttribute("style")//it is used to remove style attrb from your element
```

Comment: I need it to be in the code behind, not javascript.

Comment: My title says to remove the Style from Code Behind, meaning aspx.vb or aspx.cs, not on the client side (javascript).